# Trying to absolute center a div in IE8-11 and Chrome/Firefox

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have reviewed a number of posts/questions regarding this, and so far, I have come up with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
<style>
div.center {
    /* This centers the div horizontally and vertically, Except in IE 8-11 */
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 430px;
    height: 325px;
    background: #d2dfed;
}
</style>
    <body>
        <div class="center">
            <p>This page is reserved for a custom introduction to the system for your organization.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This works great in Chrome, but in IE, my box is still top and left justified.

Straight up, I am looking for a HTML+CSS solution to this.  I know it can be done in Javascript, but this is a page we're deploying to our customers so they can add their own text to our website, and the simpler we can keep it, the less likely they will mess it up, requiring us to intervene.

Comment: Are you opposed to using some JavaScript to do this? I'm a programmer more-so than designer, so I tend to favor JS and jQuery, but I see your tags only include CSS...

Comment: I am not opposed to js, but this is a sample page we're giving to our customers, and *they* would be opposed to js.  I'm confident this can be done in HTML+CSS, so that's what I'm wanting in my answer.

Comment: What version(s) of IE have you tested on? Using dev tools it seems to render fine above IE7. Do your customers need to support IE7? If so, perhaps consider wrapping it in a DIV, and use text-align:center on the wrapper, though this won't account for top positioning.

Comment: It seems it's more complicated than I thought.  In testing with IE11, if I open it directly, from a local file, it renders correctly.  If I push it up to our website, which runs through IIS7, it renders incorrectly.  This seems to be an issue, rather, with our IIS Website definition rather than a CSS/HTML issue.

Comment: Sounds like compatibility view settings to me - in IE, try ALT > Tools > Compatibility View Settings. Make sure the domain where you're putting the file is not added to the list, and uncheck "Display intranet sites..." if you're in a domain-based environment. If this fixes the issue, consider adding an IE=Edge meta tag.

Comment: Yes, thank you, Mark.  My browser was rendering pages from that site in Compatibility mode, *and* the site was set in IIS with the header tab IE=EmulateIE7.  Remove both of those, and it now renders correctly in IE7 and IE11.  Can you add an answer, so I can Accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page renders properly in all versions of Internet Explorer higher than IE 7. It would seem this is related to compatibility view settings. You can add an IE=Edge meta tag (or as you mentioned, remove any IIS headers regarding IE emulation), to ensure the browser uses the newest rendering engine it can. One thing to keep in mind, which always pops up on me, is that IE by default enabled the "Display intranet sites in compatibility view" option - so all internal pages in a domain-based environment will appear in compatibility mode on a fresh install of IE (unless meta tags force off the setting).

If your clients do wish to support <=IE7, you could look into adding a polyfill (which will allow older browsers to act like they support newer HTML5/CSS3 elements), but that will likely require links to external content (from a CDN) or additional files, which if they're just looking for a template may not work out.

Thank you for your consideration!